# System.setErr() doesn't restore console logging after stderr closed

Tags: java, logging, stderr, java.util.logging

My app uses [`System.setErr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr-java.io.PrintStream-) to change `stderr` to a stream which will eventually be closed.  Immediately after it's closed I immediately use `System.setErr()` again to change `stderr` to a working stream, which goes fine for when my code does something like `System.err.println()`, but logging with [`java.util.logging`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)  to the console (that is, to `stderr`) no longer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I had to [re-read the logging configuration file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration--) and then put back in the [console logging handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html) myself:

```
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.Loggger;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;

...

System.setErr(otherStream);

try {
    LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration();
}
catch(java.io.IOException e) {
    // ...
}

Logger.getGlobal().addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

The ConsoleHandler captures a reference to System.err during construction.  Another solution is to replace all ConsoleHandler in the log tree.

```
    LogManager m = LogManager.getLogManager();
    synchronized (m) {
        Enumeration<String> names = m.getLoggerNames();
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            Logger logger = m.getLogger(names.nextElement());
            if (logger != null) {
                for (Handler h : logger.getHandlers()) {
                    if (h.getClass() == ConsoleHandler.class) {
                        logger.removeHandler(h);
                        h.close();
                        logger.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
System.err.println("This is written to stderr");

// this is stderr
PrintStream oldErr = System.err;

try {
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(new File("/path/to/file")));
} catch(Exception e) {
}


System.err.println("This is written to the file");

// note that System.err wouldn't work here because System.err is no longer stderr
// but you preserved stderr in oldErr
try {
    System.setErr(oldErr);
} catch(Exception e) {
}

System.err.println("This is written to stderr again");
```